# How can you stop ordering of InputField entries?

Tags: hold, inputfield

I have:

```
InputField[Dynamic[d]]

Dynamic[d]
```

If I enter e.g.

```
a b x^5 h m
```

the entry automatically gets sorted, as per screen grab:

[image]

What is the best way to keep symbols entered into `InputField` in the same order that you entered them so that they always display in that order?

What I am actually wanting to do is enter some text that contains things like subscripts and superscripts, integrals ... `InputField[expr, String]` is not the answer. On the other hand if I use

```
InputField[Dynamic[d], Hold[Expression]]
```

and then

```
d /. {Times -> List, Power -> Superscript} // ReleaseHold
```

I get a list that I can do things with:

[image]

For example I could wrap `Row` with a default spacer or `TextCell` and so on around it. But this seems quite an indirect way of doing things.

**Edit**

Adding `HoldForm` to the second argument to `Dynamic` doesn't appear to offer any advantage and as Andrew points out you can end up with nested `HoldForm`. So I think this is not a good solution -- maybe a backwards step actually.

[image]

For Andrew's solution, using `Boxes` in `InputField` doesn't, in itself, prevent ordering when you eventually release `Hold` (e.g. after using `MakeExpression`). i.e. I don't see how to avoid apply a hold of some type and removing `Times` to stop the ordering.

[image]

So using `Boxes` may in general provide more flexibility but I'm struggling to see how it adds anything for this specific problem.

Comment: Idiomatically, I'd be using `HoldForm[]` instead of `Hold[]`...

Comment: You can't render an input field if you use `HoldForm` or `HoldForm[Expression]`

Comment: Huh. That is rather peculiar behavior...

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like

```
InputField[Dynamic[d, (d = HoldForm @@ #) &], Hold[Expression]]
```

This will wrap the expression typed into the input field in `HoldForm`.

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Note, this leads to a new layer of HoldForm appearing after each edit. E.g. after a few edits you will have `FullForm[d]` => `HoldForm[HoldForm[HoldForm[HoldForm[HoldForm[HoldForm[abc]]]]]]`.

Comment: I do see it in Mathematica 7 with these steps: Type `Dynamic[FullForm[d]]`. Now enter something like asdf into the InputField. Press Enter to trigger the Dynamic update. Now click inside the InputField, say after the "s". Press backspace, enter a different letter, and press Enter again. Repeat. I get another layer of HoldForm each time.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have any advantage over using plain vanilla `Dynamic[d]` as per what I have described in the question. See edit.

Comment: @Andrew okay, I see it now.

Answer (score 5):

Since you said you wanted text input containing subscripts, superscripts, etc, it sounds like you just want Mathematica's box language:

```
InputField[Dynamic[d], Boxes]
```

Now d is boxes, such as

```
In[39]:= FullForm[d]

Out[39]//FullForm=SuperscriptBox["a","b"]
```

You can convert them to expressions with [MakeExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MakeExpression.html) or [ToExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToExpression.html), or interpret them any other way you need to.

Comment: Very good point - +1.

Comment: That doesn't seem to prevent the automatic ordering when `Hold` is released.